# If no argument is given to mandatory option, zparseopts takes next option as the argument

Tags: shell-script, command-line, zsh, options

I am using **zsh 5.4.2**. The function that is causing issue is:

```
function zp () {
    zparseopts -E -watch:=o_watch -show=o_show
    echo "show            : $o_show"
    echo "watch           : $o_watch"
}
```

Output:

```
$ zp  --show --watch "Watching"
show            : --show
watch           : --watch Watching
    
$ zp  --watch --show 
show            : 
watch           : --watch --show
```

You can see that, If I do not pass a value to `--watch` (which's argument is mandatory) then it takes the next option in this case `--show` as the argument. It should actually show an error like `zp:zparseopts:1: missing argument for option: -watch`

Why is `--watch` taking `--show` as an argument instead of throwing an error?

Comment: That's not specific to zsh. Most tools I know do the same thing (e.g., `grep -f -e ...` will look for a file named `-e`).

Comment: I did not know that, I thought it was a bug.

Comment: So, how to throw an error if someone mistakenly do not give argument to a mandatory option (using zparseopts).

Comment: If you are absolutely certain that the argument cannot begin with a `-`, then you can check for that. But in general, that's not always true. (For example, that's one of the main uses of `-e` with `grep`: If you want to look for the pattern `-v` in a file, you would need `grep -e -v ...`. That `-v` is a valid option should *not* block the use of `-v` as an argument to `-e`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For comparison, I'm pretty sure that's how the GNU C function `getopt_long` also works, e.g. with GNU ls:

```
$ ls --sort --foo
ls: invalid argument ‘--foo’ for ‘--sort’
Valid arguments are:
...
```

If you made the argument to `--walk` optional, `zparseopts` would take `--watch --show` as two arguments:

> In all cases, option-arguments must appear either immediately following the option in the same positional parameter or in the next one. Even an optional argument may appear in the next parameter, unless it begins with a ‘-’.

But it seems that the user just needs to know which options take arguments, which also happens with short options, e.g. `tar -tzf` is quite different from `tar -tfz`.

Using (only) `--sort=whatever` would, in my opinion, make it clearer, but `zparseopts` doesn't even really support `=` directly. (`--sort=whatever` would give `=whatever` as the argument value). And that doesn't really work for short options.

Comment: this is how I handle the `=` when parsing opts
`sort=${${sort:+"${sort[2]/#=/}"}:-default}`